# touchSwipe jquery click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using touchSwipe plugin of jquery to convert swipe into click .

it seems to be working as when i swipe pages refresh or try to reach next page but same content is being displayed.

i have doubt in this line of code for next click/swipe.

```
         window.location.href='http://something.com/aakarsha/2559277';
```

here is my fiddle.Any help will be great

https://jsfiddle.net/bydbest/9gsgLqst/

here is direct link

http://something.com/aakarsha/2559277

```
  <html><body>
<p><div class="content_main_div div_100_per"><div id="timeline_content"><div><div class="content_box_main">


    <div class="messagelove_box" style="" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_title"></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_text"><div style="position: absolute; top: 35%; left: 0%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 35%; right: 0%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"></div>
<div id="detail_view" class="detail_view"><div class="detail_view_m" id="detail_view_m"><img src="http://image.something.com/misc/lazyg/aakarsha/people/aakarsha_aakarsha_photoshoot_stills_027_jpg_700_1052__mxoWV4za.sized.jpg" width="99%" alt="aakarsha" title="aakarsha"/><a href="http://something.com/aakarsha/2559276" class="view_pl" id="view_pl" hidefocus="true"></a>   
<a href="http://something.com/aakarsha/2559276" class="view_nr" id="view_nr" hidefocus="true"></a></div><a style="top: 188.5px;" id="view_prev" class="view_prev prev" href="http://something.com/aakarsha/2559276"></a>    
<a style="top: 188.5px;" id="view_next" class="view_next next" href="http://something.com/aakarsha/2559276"></a></div> </div><div class="content_box_5"><span class="vote" data-name="up" id="2559277"><span class="lipos">0 Likes</span></span></div> </div></div>
</div><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.something.com/app/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").swipe({
  swipe: function(event) {
   window.location.href='http://something.com/aakarsha/2559277';

  },
   threshold: 75,
 excludedElements: "label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe"
});

</script>   

</body>

</html>
```

i have gone through github and aware about the blocking of anchor tag so excluded the same in javascript. then also its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. it was the link which was causing problem. it works just fine now.enjoy